# R metafor forest-plots: xlim seems to be wrongly ignored

Tags: r

I am using `forest.rma` in the R package `metafor`. I want to use the `xlim` argument to specify the width of the plot. But this gets overridden when one of the x-values is outside that range. Here are two examples:

```
library(metafor)
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
rmaObject <- rma.uni(yi=c(1.3, -16), sei=c(0.8, 0.7)) 
forest(rmaObject, atransf=exp, xlim=c(-5,12), alim=c(-5,12))$xlim
forest(rmaObject, atransf=exp, xlim=c(-5,12))$xlim
```

In both cases I think the function should follow my instruction to use `xlim=c(-5,12)` and draw just a left arrowhead for the second bar, to show that the whole of the bar lies outside the left of the plot. But as the console output shows the first one sets `xlim` to `c(-16,12)` and the second one sets it to `c(-20,12)`.

In other words `forest` forces `xlim` to encompass both bars completely, but I don't think it should do that if I specify `xlim`, and especially not if I specify `alim` as well. Is there an easy way for me to fix this?

The numbers in this example are real, though I have omitted most of my studies (i.e. values of `yi` and `sei`), which are mostly in the area of 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the development version of `metafor` as described here:

http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/installation#development_version

It deals with this better. It still forces `xlim` to encompass the `yi` values, but no longer for `alim`. The summary polygon at the bottom still looks like crap though (I haven't built in any code to cut off the polygon shape at the `alim` values -- not as trivial as it may seem), but this may not be an issue once you add the rest of the studies.

Comment: Thanks, but that still gives the exact same output when you run my code, I think (except that the x-axis labels are now 0 instead of 0.00 in the second forest-plot). It would be very useful if the user was able to specify `xlim` and not have this overridden. (Previously I was using version 1.9-7 of the package, in case that is relevant, and the development version we are talking about is 1.9-9.)

Comment: Yes, 1.9-9 is the development version. Indeed, if you use `xlim=c(-5,12), alim=c(-5,12)`, then the plot limits will be changed to `-16` and `12`, since the smallest outcome is `-16`. I need to think about removing even that restriction (before, the `alim` values were forced to encompass the range of the outcomes, but no longer). Really, the only change needed is commenting out lines 415 and 416 in https://github.com/wviechtb/metafor/blob/master/R/forest.rma.r. So you could always fork the repository and create your own version of metafor.

Comment: Thank you. I commented out those two lines and it worked. (And obviously I would like to vote in favour of removing that overriding in future versions of the package!)

Comment: Ok, I'll give this some thought.